# How to upgrade minikube?

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube

I had installed *minikube* a few months ago and wanted to upgrade as newer versions are available.

I am unable to find out how to upgrade *minikube*. I see a feature request for an upgrade command here - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1171

I tried to then uninstall *minikube* and hit another brickwall again. I don't see a command to uninstall *minikube*. The information that came closest to this was not very helpful - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1043

I guess we need ways to upgrade these (at least once every 6 months or so).

Comment: What are you requirements for upgrading? Do you need to keep all of the Kubernetes objects in etcd?

Comment: I think this is an advanced use-case which minikube was not meant to support. It's more for a kick-the-tires type of experience, not a full-fledged production setup.

Comment: @IanLewis - would like to keep the objects in etcd. Wouldn't want to lose them as part of an upgrade.

Answer (score 97):

Before reinstall minikube (OS X), check the following:

- Make sure that you have `brew` updated:

  ```
  brew update
  ```
- Make sure that you already have `cask` installed:

  ```
  brew cask install minikube --verbose
  ```

Finally, execute the following command in the same directory you've installed minikube previously (usually `/usr/local/bin/`):

```
brew cask reinstall minikube
```

If you see an output similar to this:

`Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/minikube'; not linking.`

- Remove the existing binary:

  ```
  rm /usr/local/bin/minikube
  ```

Now, you should able to reinstall (upgrade) minikube. :)

Comment: I don't even have brew installed. I guess in the past there were other ways to install minikube.

Comment: what's `macdown`, do we have to install it?

Comment: `macdown` is a Markdown editor for Mac. https://macdown.uranusjr.com
Appears to have been mistakenly typed (instead of `minikube`). Answer has been edited.

Comment: ```minikube``` is no longer available as a ```cask```

Answer (score 44):

```
brew upgrade minikube
```

Just upgrade minikube with brew

Comment: Just make sure minikube is not running. If it is, stop, upgrade, start and will automatically download the rest needed.

Answer (score 31):

This should do the trick.

```
brew cask reinstall minikube
```

Comment: "As of early 2020, minikube is no more available as a cask. You need to run `brew upgrade minikube`"

Answer (score 20):

First, unlink the existing minikube from `/usr/local/bin` then reinstall:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/minikube    # unlink existing minikube

$ brew update                            # update brew itself
$ brew cask reinstall minikube           # reinstall latest minikube
```

Comment: yes, this is the recommendation on the official website: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/macos/

Answer (score 12):

An updated way is to use this:

```
brew cask upgrade minikube
```

Answer (score 11):

Process to update:

- Minikube is an executable: Re-install minikube is an upgrade.
- Optionally you can remove ~/.minikube which will make minikube completely re-initialize and also update your kubernetes version (if a new version has been made available for minikube).

Comment: That's right. We can start here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Answer (score 10):

```
minikube delete
sudo rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

re-install minikube and it should work

Answer (score 9):

if you are using **Windows** machine and **Chocolatey** package manager -

Step 1: run **PowerShell** as administrator

Step 2: run following command `choco upgrade minikube`

More on chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/

Answer (score 8):

As of early 2020, and based on the guidance provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670370/516512), minikube is no more available as a `cask`. You need to run:

```
brew install minikube
```

Comment: For those getting "Error: Cask 'minikube' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists." this is the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Minikube is no longer available in `cask` and calling `brew cask` while performing install, upgrade, or reinstall is deprecated! Use the below syntax instead:

Make sure brew is updated:

```sh
brew update
```

Then, to install, use:

```sh
brew install minikube
```

To upgrade, use:

```sh
brew upgrade minikube
```

To reinstall, use:

```sh
brew reinstall minikube
```

Answer (score 3):

On linux:

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v1.22.0/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo cp minikube /usr/local/bin/ && rm minikube
```

Change the version you want to download. Above script uses 1.22.0

Answer (score 1):

brew reinstall minikube --cask did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

[image]I simply go to official Minikube site [doc](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) and follow the Step #1 Installation, select OS, architecture etc.
in the box you get a command to upgrade/install the latest/appropriate version. As shown in the snip form the official minikube webpage.

Answer (score -1):

In order to upgrade in Windows, type:

```
minikube start
```

The following is the output you will get (make sure you are connected to internet):

> Here is a newer version of Minikube available (v0.28.0). Download it here: 
>   https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.28.0

if you don't get the above message then first run
    **minikube config set WantUpdateNotification true**
then do,
    **minikube start**

Before that, remove all the Minikube links from the system:

1. Remove the previous installation path.
2. From this folder, remove `c:\Users\<user-name>\ .kube` folder.

Comment: Just run `minikube start --kubernetes-version=v{Version}` to run the update to the specified version from the message.