# minikube tunnel throws an exception

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a similar issue as below with exposing kubernetes services via type: LoadBalancer on my local minikube cluster. 
[LoadBalancer support](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/384)

I saw that there is a workaround for this and it can be fixed via running the command `minikube tunnel`.
[Minikube Tunnel Design Doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/157eeeff2219afde6f085f515a5283476af6c280/docs/tunnel.md#windows)

However the command 'minikube tunnel' doesn't work for me and it throws an error of "Unknown command". Does anyone know if i am missing anything?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error symptoms are you seeing? I don't see any unresolved issue related to LoadBalancer on minikube in the link you pasted. Why are you not able to use https://github.com/elsonrodriguez/minikube-lb-patch/blob/master/README.md ?

Comment: It would help if you could clarify why you are trying to run minikube tunnel as you suggest this will resolve a problem for you but it's not clear to me what it would help you with.

Comment: FWIW the 'unknown command' response suggests that feature isn't in the version of minikube you are running.

Comment: Thanks @RyanDawson for your help. I narrowed it down the issue and saw that it's was my service that was not working. LoadBalancer is just working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tunnel feature is [quite new and may not be in your minikube version](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/3015#issuecomment-443392547) so try [upgrading to latest minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002364/how-to-upgrade-minikube)

Comment: Correct and i am using the older version of minikube https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.30.0