# How can I install minikube on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, macos-catalina

The provided methods on the Kubernetes documentation don't work and `brew cask` no longer seems to have the minikube formulae as of Mac OS Catalina.

`Error: Cask 'minikube' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

When I download it with `curl` it refuses to run with the following error.

`/bin/minikube: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

How can I install **minikube** on Mac OS Catalina. Or do I have to rollback to Mojave?

Comment: Not working for me either in 2020:
/usr/local/bin/minikube: cannot execute binary file Seems like some referring to this on catalina upgrade after the fact reference spctl: [https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5568](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5568) But there is no request at this level for a fresh install, the file seems to be a binary and cannot be run in catalina

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Minikube is no longer available as a `cask`.

Change command

```
brew cask install minikube
```

to

```
brew install minikube
```

or use

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd64 \
 && sudo install minikube-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

Answer (score 1):

> The provided methods on the Kubernetes documentation don't work and brew cask no longer seems to have the minikube formulae as of Mac OS Catalina.
>
> `Error: Cask 'minikube' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

[Minikube is no longer available as a cask](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/5750). You can install it with `brew install minikube`.

> When I download it with curl it refuses to run with the following
>   error.
>
> `/bin/minikube: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

An `Exec format error` might indicate that you're trying to execute a file that is not intended to be executed (e.g. a plain text file). Make sure the `/bin/minikube` file is actually a binary (you can test with `file /bin/minikube`, it should print 'Mach-O Executable')

Comment: Doesnt work for me either, and that file command fails with cannot open `usr/local/bin/minikube' (No such file or directory)

Comment: If `which minikube` points to `/usr/local/bin/minikube`, you could check with `ldd /usr/local/bin/minikube` if you're missing some shared libraries. Otherwise this might indicate that minikube is not installed.