# How to update kubectl to latest version and sync kubectl client and server version on MacOs (local minikube)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I've updated `kubectl client version` to the latest but I am not able to update `kubectl server version` to the latest due to which client and server versions are different. The problem is: how can I update `kubectl server version`?

P.S i'm running minikube on docker locally

````
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:50:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.22) and server (1.18) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1 ``` 



```commands which i used to update Kubectl client version are below (for mac intel chip):
Link reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/ ```
````

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002364/how-to-upgrade-minikube/64362273#64362273)?

Answer (score 1):

Posted community wiki answer for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

You need to upgrade your minikube version in order to upgrade the kubectl server version.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002364/how-to-upgrade-minikube/64362273#64362273) to upgrade minikube on macOS you just need to run these commands (since 2020):

```
brew update
brew upgrade minikube
```

If you encountered any problems, I'd suggest to fully delete minikube from your system (based on [this GitHub page](https://gist.github.com/rahulkumar-aws/65e6fbe16cc71012cef997957a1530a3)):

```
minikube stop; minikube delete &&
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) &&
rm -rf ~/.kube ~/.minikube &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/localkube /usr/local/bin/minikube &&
launchctl stop '*kubelet*.mount' &&
launchctl stop localkube.service &&
launchctl disable localkube.service &&
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/ &&
docker system prune -af --volumes
```

Then you can install minikube with the newest version from scratch by [using brew](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/):

```
brew install minikube
```

either by [downloading and installing a binary file](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/):

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd64
sudo install minikube-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```